# Computer boots only to motherboard splash screen

Tags: boot, bios, intel-pentium

I have a file server running Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit, with an Intel 915PBL motherboard and a Pentium 4 620 processor, with 2 GB of memory. Yesterday, it started booting just to the Intel Pentium 4 Motherboard splash screen. There's no option to enter the BIOS.

I pulled out the hard drive and ran chkdsk on it using my regular desktop. Chkdsk reported no bad sectors, and Acronis Drive Monitor reports that the drive is functioning at 100%. It will not let me boot to a copy of Ultimate Boot CD, either. I'm not sure where to look next.

Comment: Do you have any other peripherals or cards (etc.) in your server box?  If so, I would a) reseat the RAM b) unplug all peripherals (video cards, other hard drives, etc.) and restart.  Another option is to clear the CMOS fully (i.e. remove the power, remove the button battery, hold the power button, set the jumper to clrcmos on the board).

Comment: Just a video card, which is required, as the motherboard does not have on-board video. I haven't made any hardware changes since I built it. I'm thinking about pulling out the memory and testing it in my regular desktop.

Comment: Do you have an SSH server running on it?  How about a piezzo speaker that beeps on errors?  Either of those could help you determine that it boots without the video card.  Or use another video card.

Comment: @Davidw Make sure that RAM is compatible first. Server RAM is often buffered and/or ECC. Most desktops won't like that at all. You may actually damage the RAM that way.

Comment: It uses a standard desktop motherboard.

Comment: What is this "Pentium 4 splash screen?" Do you mean the bios splash screen?

Comment: Usually the "BIOS setup" option is hidden. Research your bios brand to see what it is for your bios. F11, F12, F10, TAB, DEL, ... could be one of those.

Comment: jpaugh, It says Intel Pentium 4 or something to that effect. I'll have to post a photo.

The computer is basically a desktop with a server OS. It's a home-build.

Comment: its hardware, memory or even a keyboard/mouse not connected. And like jpaugh mentioned, use one of those hot keys to get to BIOS... even hit F1 or F2 at the splash screen. Usually F1 means "Continue" and F2 means "enter bios".... it all might be hidden behind the splash

Comment: Ok, I was able to get it to get it to a screen that says "Entering Setup", but it does nothing beyond that for quite a while.

Comment: I borrowed a stick of memory from the regular desktop, and it still will not go beyond the entering setup screen.

Comment: Ok, I disconnected the CD/DVD drive, and it boots normally now. It's been acting up before, being unwilling to read disks before, and very finicky about opening.